# Is Joule / kg a dimensionless quantity?

Tags: units, si-units, unit-conversion

If (given that Mass * constant = Energy, as in E = mc²), Joule is convertible to kg,  just with a very small conversion factor, does this mean 1 Joule / kg doesn't have any unit and just equals that factor?

I am confused as Joule defined as kg * m²/s² would yield m²/s².

What am I missing?

Comment: Since $E/m=c^2$, we keep the dimension of $c^2$.

Comment: @Ghoster Oh I'm sorry, corrected it to kg. Also, idk why I multiplied instead of dividing.

Comment: *What am I missing?* That $c$ is the symbol for the speed of light, and not some dimensionless constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That constant has units. The units of c are m/s.

Comment: Right, I completely forgot that c is a velocity and not a dimensionless factor.